# How to get points of lines tangent to 2 circles

Tags: geometry

How do you get the points of lines tangent to two circles, where both starting point and end point of line are exactly touching their respective circles?

[image]

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I've encountered this problem in software development before, although you might get a better answer in the math group.

Answer (score 0):

The angles at p4 and p2 are 90 degrees. If you conceptually put them at the base of a quadrilateral p2-p4-c2-c1, you can get the angle at C2 (from p4-c1) and at c1 (from p2-c2). With that angle, you can easily construct it.